# Transform skew causes 0.5px vertical shift in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transforms

I'm making a shape with skewed right side.

Here is the code:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #2b4450;
  color: white;
  font: bold 16.67px'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
h2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 34px;
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform: skew(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
```

Looks good in Chrome and Firefox but not IE. In IE pseudo element is shifted about 0.5px up and sometimes 0.5px down and this is how it looks:

[image]

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3nmha5sf/1/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are borders an option? Like https://jsfiddle.net/3nmha5sf/5/. BTW; which version of IE? Because I don't see this distortion in IE11.

Comment: @Seika85 your example looks good but in that case pseudo element gives extra invisible clickable area. I use IE11 (11.0.9600.17498). I guess I have 2 options, to use image or to leave it as it is, hope this IE behavior is rarely found :)

Comment: There you are: https://jsfiddle.net/3nmha5sf/6/  
No additional clickable area. I'll put it in an answer...

Comment: Or easier: https://jsfiddle.net/3nmha5sf/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If borders are an option: https://jsfiddle.net/3nmha5sf/9/

**HTML**

```
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>ALL CAMPAIGNS</h2>
```

**SCSS**

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #2b4450;
    color: white;
    font: bold 16.67px 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 0 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        right: -20px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        background: none;
        height: 0;
        border: solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #2b4450;
        border-width: 0 20px 35px;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Looks good in my IE, thanks :) will take as idea to not use transforms if there is another way